# Will I always get the warning that quests may fail?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Before traveling to the Isle of Mists you get a warning specifying that some quest may fail if you go past this point. The first time I was about to cross this point I double checked that I had [completed all the quests](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Isle_of_Mists_(quest)#.C2.A0Notes) listed on the Wiki. After crossing I got a quest failed notification for [Berengar's Blade](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Berengar%27s_Blade) (I had already discovered the quest before crossing). I loaded up an old save and completed the Berengar's Blade quest, and crossed again. I haven't gotten any quest failed notifications after crossing but I did get the warning again. I'm concerned that I might be missing some secondary that isn't listed on the Wiki since I might not get a quest failed notification if I haven't discovered the quest in the first place.

So my question is do you always get that warning or will it only be present if you are going to miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have always received this warning on every play through I have done even though I have completed all the secondary quests. So I think you always get it.

The quests that can fail all involve the main characters. Things like Witcher Contracts and Treasure Hunts are OK.

Comment: In general, If you've recruited all available helpers to Kaer Morhen, then you've completed all the relevant quests.

Comment: @tjd There are other quests that will fail as well as these such as the Berengar's Blade quest mentioned in the question

Comment: Well I have done at least 6 play throughs (probably more I've lost count). I think it unlikely I have missed anything. Only the developers can give you an absolutely definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the main quests, but it's definitely possible to fail a secondary quest without being warned. As an example if you need to obtain a Gwent card from an NPC, and that NPC dies, then you will fail the quest